# DoCmd.OpenForm opens form in read only mode. Acces 2016 (VBA)

Tags: vba, local, adodb, ms-access-2016

I am playing around with access trying to simulate a client-server structure with one frontend and one backend file. My frontend contains an index form which lists all the records of my backend table. A double-click on an entry is supposed to open the corresponding single form and it does just that, but once it's open, I can not edit the single page (similar to this post from a while back [vba access form not read-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30508184/vba-access-form-not-read-only)). In the lefthand lower corner just flashes a short "Formular ist schreibgeschützt" which means the form is in read only mode.

As a side note: I did not create either access database myself. They were provided as part of a training course.

I tried several things but clearly, I don't have a firm grasp of anything VBA related and so I seem to be missing something (probably something obvious).

Since I was not sure whether or not it may be related to NTFS permissions (I don't usually work on windows) I put both files (backend and frontend) in a folder on my c drive and gave everyone full access to that folder, even though I am the only one trying to work with them, just to be sure. Since that did not change anything, I gathered that the error has to be in my code.

I'll give a logical list of possibly relevant bits of code, though that does not reflect the order in which I tried to find solutions before.

I use early binding ADODB to connect to the access 2016 backend database, so in the References "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library" is active.

The connection, as well as the recordset and the base sql string, are declared globally (in their own module), so they can be accessed throughout the code.

```
Public Conn As ADODB.Connection
Public rs As ADODB.Recordset
Public xSQL As String
```

The connection is established when loading the index form (which is loaded when opening the database). At first, I had no conn.Mode set, then I tried adModeReadWrite and adModeShareDenyNone to no avail.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

  Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection
  Conn.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0"
  Conn.ConnectionString = CurrentProject.Path & "\MitgliederlisteDaten.accdb"
  Conn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
  Conn.Mode = adModeShareDenyNone

  Conn.Open

  'conn.state at this point is 1

  xSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblMitgliederliste INNER JOIN tblTyp ON tblMitgliederliste.TypID = tblTyp.TypID"

  Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
  rs.Open xSQL, Conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

  Set Me.Recordset = rs

End Sub
```

The connection does work insofar the index form and the single form are displayed correctly.

A double-click on an entry is supposed to open the respective single form which is done with a simple docmd.openform, though I tried setting the DataMode to acFormEdit

```
Private Sub MitgliedsNr_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
  DoCmd.OpenForm "frmAdresse"
  'DoCmd.OpenForm "frmAdresse", , , , acFormEdit
End Sub
```

Populating the single form happens in the corresponding load event.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

  Dim memberSQL As String
  memberSQL = xSQL & " WHERE MitgliedsNr= " & Forms("frmAdressliste")!MitgliedsNr

  Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
  rs.Open memberSQL, Conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockPessimistic
  Set Me.Recordset = rs

  Dim cmbSQL As String
  cmbSQL = "SELECT TypID, Typ FROM tblTyp IN '"
  cmbSQL = cmbSQL & CurrentProject.Path & "\MitgliederlisteDaten.accdb"
  cmbSQL = cmbSQL & "' ORDER BY Typ"

  Me.cmbTyp.RowSource = cmbSQL
  Me.cmbTyp.ColumnCount = 2
  Me.cmbTyp.ColumnWidths = "0cm;4cm"
  Me.Form.AllowEdits = True

End Sub
```

I've been staring it for so long that I can't make out the probably glaring error. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance for any answer or constructive criticism.

Kind regards

Comment: Are you sure the form isn't open elsewhere already, perhaps on another machine, or in another (possibly hidden) instance somewhere?  To make sure, reboot your machine as well as the one on which the database is located.

Comment: That connection string doesn't look valid, it's just a file location. You can get the default ADO connection string by running `Debug.Print CurrentProject.Connection` on the backend, and use that on your front end, and just use that. You can also try using the default connection string for forms by using `Debug.Print CurrentProject.AccessConnection`, but that provider is relatively undocumented.

Comment: @ ashleedawg thanks for the suggestion. I just finished rebooting but the outcome is still the same.

Comment: @ Erik von Asmuth thanks. I will try that but if the connection string was invalid, would the conn.state ever be 1 ? Oh, i failed to mention that, sorry. But when I check the conn.state after conn.open it shows 1

Comment: If it's plain nonsense, no, it wouldn't. If it misses parts or contains invalid parameters, it might exhibit weird behaviour. But anyway, try using the `AccessConnection` one. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/currentproject-accessconnection-property-access) says: You should use the AccessConnection property if you intend to create ADO recordsets that will be bound to Access forms. The form will not be updateable unless it is created by using the OLE DB Provider for Microsoft Access, even if the recordset is updateable in ADO

Comment: Note: the `AccessConnection` connection uses the `Microsoft.Access.OLEDB.10.0` provider, which apparently is different from the `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0` provider (it's older and undocumented), but it's specifically intended for updateable forms. I've had success in the past with updateable forms with the `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` provider, though.

Comment: @ Erik von Asmuth thanks for your patience, I haven't run away I am currently trying to stuff the output of `Debug.Print CurrentProject.Connection` into my a connection string but that is producing errors so far that I have to get out of the way first. You are right though, the provider is `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` but I am curious about `User ID=Admin` since that is not my windows account.

Comment: The `User ID=Admin` refers to user-level security, a deprecated security technique. The default user is admin, the default password is blank. It's not at all supported on accdb files, but it doesn't hurt, and most default connection strings still include it.

Comment: (If you use [this technique](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/285822/how-to-determine-who-is-logged-on-to-a-database-by-using-microsoft-jet), you will see you're still logged in as Admin in your access database, even though User-level security is unsupported).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173244/discussion-between-j4g0-and-erik-von-asmuth).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your help. I just finished rebuilding the whole thing from scratch and now it works. I don't get why though, yet.

In order to get to the trouble point as fast as possible, I built the xSQL string which I Used to build the recordset for my index form differently.
Instead of

```
xSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblMitgliederliste INNER JOIN tblTyp ON tblMitgliederliste.TypID = tblTyp.TypID"
```

I went with the much shorter

```
xSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblMitgliederliste"
```

planning on implementing the JOIN later on. But that was actually all it took since now I can open the single form via double click and edit and delete to my heart's content without changing anything else from my original code.

Once I'm done backing it up and getting some fresh air, I'll start playing around with the extended string to see if it really was the problem, though I don't quite know how it could have been.